# Arel: select from function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', date_range) 
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(:start_date, :end_date, :interval) as date_range
```

Is it possible to use `GENERATE_SERIES(...)` as a table (data source)? Ideally, it would look like this:

```
t = series(start, end, as: 'date_range')
dt = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_TRUNC', ['hour', t[:date_range]])
t.project(dt)
```

**Upd1**. Why do I need `GENERATE_SERIES`? I have some data that I need to process with regards to timestamps this data was available on, and output it as a 2D plot. As a simple example consider a `clickstream` = (`id`, `created_at`). I want to plot a number of clicks made prior to a certain date with regards to a given datetime grid (i.e `Nov 17, Nov 18, Nov 19, ..., Nov 30`). And the thing is I want this all happen inside PostgreSQL.

**Upd2**. Example query without variables could look like this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', date_range) FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2015-01-01 00:15:38'::TIMESTAMP, '2015-01-10 23:59:59'::TIMESTAMP, '1 HOUR') as date_range;
```

Comment: Can you briefly describe what you are trying to achieve, apart from the code that you used? May be there is a better or different solution that doesn't involve the `generate_series` function.

Comment: Please provide an actual example query without variables.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I updated the question with a motivation behind generate series. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @dankohn I updated the question with the actual query. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to simply build all the necessary parts of the AST manually

```
def timestamp(ts)
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'CAST', [
      Arel::Nodes::As.new(
        Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(ts),
        Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('timestamp')
      )
    ]
  )
end

def series(from, to, by, options = {})
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'GENERATE_SERIES', [
      timestamp(from),
      timestamp(to),
      Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(by)
    ]
  ).as(options.fetch(:as, 'series'))
end

def date_trunc(by, attribute)
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'DATE_TRUNC', [Arel.sql("'#{by}'"), attribute]
  )
end

date_range = Arel::Table.new('date_range')
result = date_range.
  from(series(5.days.ago, 4.days.ago, "'1 hour'", as: 'date_range')).
  project(date_trunc('hour', date_range[:date_range]))
```

Test:

```
User.find_by_sql(result.to_sql).to_a.map &:attributes    

SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', "date_range"."date_range")
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
  CAST('2015-02-03 21:29:22.729188' AS timestamp),
  CAST('2015-02-04 21:29:22.729633' AS timestamp),
  '1 hour'
) AS date_range

[{"date_trunc"=>2015-02-03 21:00:00 UTC, "id"=>nil},
 {"date_trunc"=>2015-02-03 22:00:00 UTC, "id"=>nil},
 {"date_trunc"=>2015-02-03 23:00:00 UTC, "id"=>nil},
 {"date_trunc"=>2015-02-04 00:00:00 UTC, "id"=>nil},
# ...
 {"date_trunc"=>2015-02-04 21:00:00 UTC, "id"=>nil}]
```

Comment: Is that really work. I think it should be `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(timestamp(from))`

Comment: This doesn't work in newer versions of Arel because the `from` method now takes no arguments.